# Download Ubuntu 16.04 with a specific version of kernel

Tags: 16.04, kernel

Is it possible to download a Ubuntu 16.04 installation image with a specific version of kernel e.g. 4.10?

Current image has kernel 4.15 by default. Downgrading kernel process is not straight forward

Answer (score 0):

Kernel 4.10 is not supported on Ubuntu 16.04 any more.

Supported kernels are 4.4 and 4.15.

You can install a mainline kernel at your own risk.

Ubuntu 16.04.3 iso had the 4.10 kernel. Nut after a first package upgrade it will switch to the 4.15.

Comment: I am just wondering whether I download an iso with e.g. 4.10 kernel, then downgrade the kernel to 4.4. Does it result in the same system if installed from an iso with kernel 4.4 right from the start? the upgrade can be avoided by using "hold" right?